# What are the SOAP Messages on the Help Page of an ASMX Web Service Method?

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, asmx

I am currently studying Web Services and after doing a sample practise in a .asmx file, I notice that below the sample method output page, there's many SOAP related messages like the ones below, can anyone tell me what are these messages for? Thanks.

SOAP 1.1
The following is a sample SOAP 1.1 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /SecurityWebService/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://tempuri.org/GetSecurityInfo"

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSecurityInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Code>string</Code>
    </GetSecurityInfo>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <GetSecurityInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetSecurityInfoResult>
        <Code>string</Code>
        <CompanyName>string</CompanyName>
        <Price>double</Price>
      </GetSecurityInfoResult>
    </GetSecurityInfoResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

SOAP 1.2
The following is a sample SOAP 1.2 request and response. The placeholders shown need to be replaced with actual values.

```
POST /SecurityWebService/Service.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetSecurityInfo xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <Code>string</Code>
    </GetSecurityInfo>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <GetSecurityInfoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetSecurityInfoResult>
        <Code>string</Code>
        <CompanyName>string</CompanyName>
        <Price>double</Price>
      </GetSecurityInfoResult>
    </GetSecurityInfoResponse>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
```

Comment: FYI, you're starting off in the past. Microsoft considers ASMX services to be a "legacy technology". All new development should use WCF.

Comment: These are sample request and response messages.

Comment: Yes I understand and aware of WCF, but somehow my company is still using this legacy tech.

Comment: Direct their attention to [Microsoft says: ASMX Web Services are a “Legacy Technology”](http://johnwsaunders3.wordpress.com/2009/07/03/microsoft-says-asmx-web-services-are-a-%E2%80%9Clegacy-technology%E2%80%9D/) and maybe they'll change their minds. You might also remind them that only critical security bugs are being fixed in ASMX web services and the XML Serializer technology it depends on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These are messages encoded in the [SOAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP) protocol. .NET kinda puts that in a "black box" that for you, so that you don't have to handle SOAP messages creation and parsing yourself.